# Script for XCode UI Test Cases

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode-ui-testing

I was wondering whether it is possible in XCode UI-tests to write a "script-file" which calls my tests with different arguements for example.

Right now I have about 10 tests in three different test-classes. Now, I'm looking to have another file where I can call something like:

```
test1(argx)
test2(argx)
test1(argy)
test2(argy)
```

Do you have any suggestions?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

i have a proposition. Work with environment variable. In you Info.pflist file add some variables (you arguments). something like:

```
key               TYPE        value

MY_ARGUMENT       String      $(MY_ARGUMENT)
```

you can read this variable in you code with NSBundle. Something like:

```
if let myArgument = NSBundle(forClass: self.dynamicType).objectForInfoDictionaryKey("MY_ARGUMENT") as? String {
            work with myArgument here.....       
}
```

you can set my argument when you call a command line

```
xcodebuild clean test -workspace MY_APP.xcworkspace -scheme "MY_SCHEME" -sdk iphonesimulator -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 6,OS=9.3' MY_ARGUMENT=the value of the variable
```

Try it.